# VBA script to format addresses

Tags: vba, gis, arcmap

I am trying to add data in Arcmap 10.4.1 to format addresses. I've never used any VBA or Python before. This code has worked to some degree. I am stuck with issues regarding double spacing and duplicate fields as in when a locality (town) and post town are the same. I was wondering if there is a way to only inset the fields if there are characters present and if there is a way to only insert POST_TOWN if it is different to LOCALITY_N

I tried following a tutorial for a VBA script to pull it all together in a new field. I added the code below which pulls all the fields together.

```
[SAO_NUM] &" " & [SAO_TEXT] &" " & [PAO_NUM] &" " & [PAO_TEXT] &" " & [STREET_DES] &" " & [LOCALITY_N] &" " & [POST_TOWN] & " " & "LANCASHIRE" & " " & [POSTCODE]
```

An example of an entry is below where there are double spaces

```
 UNIT 7   BROCKHOLES GARAGE WINDERMERE ROAD BROCKHOLES PRESTON LANCASHIRE PR6 0GH
```

Another example where the LOCALITY_N and POST_TOWN are the same is below

```
  20   ROSSALL GATE PRESTON PRESTON LANCASHIRE PR7 8AB
```

These are fictional addresses but with the same formatting issues. Any help or guidance appreciated

Comment: Where does python fit into your question?

Comment: You need to show more of your code, if you're using VBA you can easily test the `Len()` of the string before adding it to your final string.

Comment: Is the problem that you want to eliminate the internal double spaces in the final string? Rather than hard-wiring the spaces into the string, it might be better to place the parts you want to keep in an array and then `Join()` them with a space delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate your statement in a `Replace(string,find,replacewith)` vbscript function which as per the line below is used to replace double spaces `"  "` with nothing `""` string.

```
Replace([SAO_NUM] &" " & [SAO_TEXT] &" " & [PAO_NUM] &" " & [PAO_TEXT] &" " & [STREET_DES] &" " & [LOCALITY_N] &" " & [POST_TOWN] & " " & "LANCASHIRE" & " " & [POSTCODE],"  ","")
```

More details on this VBScript function can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_replace.asp

Comment: This does note cater for spaces in your attribute data, to remove these spaces you need to put each field in a `Trim(String)` function.  https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_trim.asp